# How to paging while every page may start form a different offset

Tags: ajax, algorithm, paging

For example: 50 rows per page

- Page1: First fetch 50 rows. row 0 to row 49, and remove 15 rows by a filter. So I have only 35 rows,  then I fetch another 50 rows. Row 50 to row 99, then I get 15 rows from these rows by the same filter to merge those 35 rows. Now I have 50 rows, but spent at lest 65 rows.
- Page2: Start with >= row 65.
- Page3: Start with >= row 115.
- Page4: Start with >= row 165.

How do I get the start offset of page2 when getting the page4?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Apply your filter before fetching data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fetching from a database, make the filter part of the query itself and let the database software do the counting for you. E.g.

```
SELECT * from myrows WHERE [condition] LIMIT 50 OFFSET 200
```

would give you the filtered records 200..249, i.e. contents of page #5.